# How to validate an item is not reselected from a dropdown again in django inline model admin?

Tags: python, django

I wish to validate an item(foreignkey) is not reselected from a dropdown again in django inline model admin in the next instance of the inline for the same parent model.How do I do it. Example: I selected a product in invoice detail inline. Same should not be selectable in another inline for the same parent invoice model admin.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this I guess you could try to create a custom validator on your ForeignKey field : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/

You can also override the clean method of your form to make sure this product hasn't already being saved for the same parent.

That's two things you can look into, if you want more detailed answer you need to provide code and more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033137/select-unselected-m2m-instance-in-django-model-form http://stackoverflow.com/users/3768672/raphael-laurent pl. revert with sample code in teh above case if you can.